Reverse Proxy DolphinDB through Nginx
I am trying to set up a proxy for my dolphindb port 8902. The http part seems working. However, I got error message when the javascript tries to establish a websocket connection: WebSocketConnectionError: ws://<my-ip>/, code: 1006 at WebSocket.<anonymous> (http://<my-ip>/path/index.js:18837:31)
nginx.conf:
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  <my-ip>;

        location /path/ {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8902/;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection        "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      600s;
            proxy_send_timeout         600s;
            proxy_read_timeout         600s;
            proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            proxy_buffers              4 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        }
    }

